# java date format wrong response

Tags: java, android, date-format

I am using this functions to convert date in display format. But return wrong resopnse.

```
date = converDateFormate("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a","2013/11/28 12:23:28");

Wrong Response: 11/28/2013 12:23 **AM**  

Right Response: 11/28/2013 12:23 **PM** (how can I get this response)


public static String converDateFormate(String oldpattern,
            String newPattern, String dateString) throws ParseException {
        if (dateString != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(oldpattern);
            Date testDate = null;
            testDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(newPattern);
            String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
            System.out.println("" + newFormat);
            return newFormat;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) at "Confusion at noon and midnight". If your input is in 24-hours format then you need to use `HH:mm:ss` in your pattern.

Answer (score 3):

small mistake .
instead of 
date = converDateFormate("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a","2013/11/28 12:23:28");

use this

date = converDateFormate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a","2013/11/28 12:23:28");

Answer (score 2):

The old pattern needs to be changed to 24 hours format(HH:mm:ss).

So you have to change the line-
"date = converDateFormate("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a","2013/11/28 12:23:28");"  to
"date = converDateFormate("yyyy/MM/dd **HH:mm:ss**", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", "2013/11/28 12:23:28");"